# Med-PC Programming Language

Tags: programming-languages

There's this programming language called Med-PC that works with animal behavior. I'm trying to learn a bit about it, but i can't seem to find any kind of books or material about it.

I've "google it" but all i seem to find are some references about it and a PDF explaining the installing of the program itself and sensors(for the experiments), not actual programming instructions.

I'm looking for some kind of guidance, documents or books, some kind of reference where i can improve and learn about this language, or if it is based on some other language. I just need some reference about it.

So i've resorted to StackOverFlow to see if anybody has worked, knows about it or can point me some links/books about it.

Comment: there is the manual, as pointed out, but also a site with examples: http://www.mednr.com/programs.htm. Thet best way to learn to use it, in my experience, is to pick an example close to what you want, and adapt it from that. Beware it is the ugliest programming language I have ever worked with, with ridiculous constraints (e.g., only 26 variables allowed, and they can only have single letter names). It works really well for behavioral experiments, but it cannot have been developed by real developers as it is a dumpster fire in terms of usability.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have stopped using the language, but that comment will be helpful for anyone that stops by for this question.

Answer (score 2):

The Med-PC program itself comes with a programming manual that teaches the language.  Alternatively, it's based off of the Pascal programming language and it accepts inline pascal code.

Comment: The manual included is very limited and doesn't have a great range of all the possibilities. I'm looking for more in-depth information. I know it was based, but i didn't knew that it would accept inline pascal code. Have to try that out.